Forgot wordpress admin password, also not receiving email to reset
Forgot wordpress admin password, also not receiving email to reset
I have a wordpress site, but I am unable to login because I forgot the password. Also I am not receiving the password reset email. changed password in phpmyadmin, but did not work

Are you sure that you hashed the new password using md5?

You Can Access your database and search for wp_users table there you Can change admin password and log in again

@Artemy Kaydash It worked, thank you!  forgot to convert in hashtag

If you have access to WP CLI, try changing your password with the wp user update command.
